# "/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^" in bash loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a Bash alias (or script) which lists which of some particular programs are currently running.

In my `.bashrc` I have set `$MY_BIN_PATH` to a directory containing all the programs of interest to me:

```
export MY_BIN_PATH=/root/repo/bin
$ > echo $MY_BIN_PATH
```

> /root/repo/bin

Listing that directory shows a number of files.  I want to `grep` the output of `ps -ef` for each of these:

```
for i in `ls $MY_BIN_PATH`; 
do
  ps -ef | grep $i | egrep -v "grep|md_m|avahi"; 
done
```

Regardless of which (if any) of the files in `$MY_BIN_PATH` are running, the output is always:

```
/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/bin/grep: Unmatched [ or [^
```

It *seems* like somehow the value of `$i` is "forgotten" in the pipe between `ps -ef` and `grep $i`.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I make it work?

Comment: @fedorqui: I'm happy to learn alternate/better methods!

Comment: Also, yes I did `grep $i` on the command line, and that worked.

Comment: I have to recognize that it was easy to say I didn't really like it but I still cannot find any better way :) Maybe to output the `ls` to a var $SOME_DIR with `|` as delimiter and then run `ps` just once and `| egrep $SOME_DIR`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check if `ls` is aliased to something.  Maybe you should use the absolute path to `ls` and without any options.  Make sure it is not system-aliased to color-ls or something.

Second, you can change the loop header to

`for i in $MY_BIN_PATH/*`

and that may fix it as well.

Comment: +1 and accept.  `ls` *was* in fact aliased, just as you suspected.

Answer (score 5):

As a start, [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Secondly, parameters needs to be properly quoted

Try this:

```
for i in $MY_BIN_PATH/*
do
  ps -ef | grep "$i" | egrep -v "grep|md_m|avahi"
done
```

To get the PID of a running process when you know the process name, use [pidof()](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof).

What are you trying to achive with the loop in the end?

Comment: Thanks.  The first line of my post explains what I'm *really* trying to do:  "I am trying to write a Bash alias (or script) which lists which of some particular programs are currently running."

Comment: Sorry for not paying attention :-)

Comment: No sweat.  You still provided valuable input.